# Cannot convert const char * to char *

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

Visual Studio c++ 2005

I am getting an error on the last line of this code.

```
int Utils::GetLengthDiff ( const char * input, int & num_subst ) 
{
    int num_wide = 0, diff = 0 ; 
    const char * start_ptr = input ; 

    num_subst = 0 ; 
    while ( ( start_ptr = strstr ( start_ptr, enc_start ) ) != NULL ) 
    {
        char * end_ptr = strstr ( start_ptr, enc_end ); // Error
```

So I changed the line to this and it worked ok

```
const char * end_ptr = strstr ( start_ptr, enc_end );
```

So why would I need to declare end_ptr as a const as well?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++ has two overloaded versions of this function. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/

```
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
      char * strstr (       char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Since your `start_ptr` is `const char *` the C++ compiler resolves to call the version that takes a `const char *` as the first parameter, that version also *returns* a `const char *`, so you have to change your return value to match.

Answer (score 2):

> So why would I need to declare end_ptr as a const as well?

For the same reason that `start_ptr` needs to be `const char*`: `strstr` returns the type `const char*` (= `char const*`) because it searches inside a constant string (the parameter you pass *to* `strstr` is also `const char*`). In particular, it’s *not* the pointer that is `const`, it’s the memory it points to. Think of it as a pointer to an immutable (i.e. constant) string. You *can* change what it points to but not the individual characters inside the string.

This is different from an unchangeable pointer which points to a mutable string, i.e. a string where you can change individual characters.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the return value from `strstr` were `char*`, with a `const char*` first parameter, as it is in C. Then you could write:

```
const char *s = "hello, world";
strstr(s, "hello")[0] = 'j';
```

The code would compile and run (with undefined behavior), but it's the kind of error which `const` was specifically designed to avoid. You've converted a `const char*` to `char*` without a cast.

C can't really do anything about it: if strstr returned `const char*` then you'd have to cast back to non-const explicitly in the case where the input is non-const and you want to modify the string. Because C++ has function overloading it can (and does) plug the loophole and make both cases work correctly. Hence in C++, the above code fails to compile, and so does your example code.